Invalid site key or not loaded in api.js, Google reCAPTCHA Enterprise
Everytime I tried to render the reCAPTCHA manually using the render function I get the following error
Error: Invalid site key or not loaded in api.js: "6Lf....."

It works fine doing it the way shown in the docs
<head>
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?render=6L..."></script>
  <!-- Your code -->
</head>
<script>
  function onClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    grecaptcha.enterprise.ready(async () => {
      const token = await grecaptcha.enterprise.execute('6L...', {action: 'LOGIN'});
    });
  }
</script>

But whenever I try:
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?render=explicit&onload=onRecaptchaLoadCallback"></script>

// recaptcha.js
function onRecaptchaLoadCallback(){
 grecaptcha.enterprise.render('recaptcha', {
        sitekey: "6L...",
        badge: 'inline',
        size: "invisible",
        callback: function () {
            console.log('recaptcha callback');
            }
    })
}

// executed upon form onsubmit
function onClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  grecaptcha.enterprise.ready(async () => {
    const token = await grecaptcha.enterprise.execute('KEY_ID', {action: 'LOGIN'});
    
  });
}


I get the above-stated error. I have already double-checked the keys and tried creating a new key, but it did not work. Any ideas as to why it doesn't work when trying to render manually?

I'm getting a similar problem, in my case the recaptcha badge appears and succeds, but the token is always null. Even when switching from the awkward await method to the standard JS promise, the token returned is null. It seems the function fires too early somehow.
